# Compute the mean for each row from a tf.SparseTensor in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to compute the mean for axis=0 for a `tf.SparseTensor`. I want something like `tf.sparse_reduce_sum`. TensorFlow doesn't provide a similar function for the mean calculation. Is there any way to count the values in each row in order to divide them with the sum?

```
indices = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5],
               [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5],
               [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4],
               [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5],
               [4, 0], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 5]], dtype=np.int64)

values = np.array([7, 6, 7, 4, 5, 4,
                   6, 7, 4, 3, 4,
                   3, 3, 1, 1,
                   1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4,
                   1, 1, 2, 3, 3], dtype=np.float64)

dense_shape = np.array([5, 6], dtype=np.int64)

tRatings = tf.SparseTensor(indices, values, dense_shape)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compute the reduced mean from the reduced sum by dividing by the size of the 0th dimension:

```
tRatings = tf.SparseTensor(indices, values, dense_shape)
reduced_sum = tf.sparse_reduce_sum(tRatings, 0)  # Sum of each row
reduced_mean = reduced_sum / tf.cast(tRatings.dense_shape[0], tf.float64)  # Mean of each row
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `get_shape()` and then multiply `shape[0] * shape[1]` this is the total number of elements

Comment: That would be the representing shape of the dense tensor. I need to count the elements of each row of the dense tensor in order to calculate the mean of each row.

Comment: Use `tf.sparse_reduce_sum(tensor, 1)` and you will get another tensor with the sum of each row as you can read in example https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_reduce_sum and then use `tf.divide(tensor, shape[1])` and you'll get the mean in each row